# Is there a way to split a flat multi-poly face into squares and triangles easily?

Tags: faces

I'm relatively new to blender (previous game was 2d) but I know the basic rules like making your mesh out of rectangle/squares and triangles. Due to a city block being mostly flat I've disregarded that rule for the top face which has worked until [this particular shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECA5d.jpg). I've tried removing doubles and recalculating normals, and all vertices on the face have the same z-co-ordinate. This means it's due to the shape and I don't want to spend time joining these vertices into squares/triangles in order to fix it, is there any way to do it easy/automatically?

Comment: I don't get the idea behind this question. If it's about how to convert Ngon into tris then press Ctrl+T with it selected. If it's about converting it to quads then try to delete the face and fill with Grid Fill. If clean quads are needed it might be required to convert into quads manually. Also depending on the purpose of the mesh converting might not be needed at all

Answer (score 1):

These functions can be useful for you. Hit ctrl+e or ctrl+f in edit mode.
[image]